# can jenkins job wait for results without taking a slot

Tags: jenkins

I am building a project in Jenkins and want to launch tests right after it,  wait 
 until the tests are finished and than run another job to analyze the results. The testing system is a close system (I can't modify it) so in order to check if the tests are finish I need to query the system every X seconds. One way to so that is to create a job that will query the system but it will take a slot (I can create 1000 slots but it looks like a hack). is there another way to make the job "sleep" while it is waiting for the next X seconds so it will not take a slot while waiting for another process to finish ?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger one Jenkins job from another. No need to make jobs sleep or anything complicated like that. Look at upstream and downstream triggers using the parameterized build plugin.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger